# Labels are printed in PDF

Tags: cross-referencing

I really don't know if I changed a thing in my preamble but suddenly all labels are printed in the form ?{label}? in the top-left of every labeled object.

My main document is

```
\documentclass[spanish,letterpaper,twoside,12pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    hypertexnames=false,
    pdftoolbar=true,       
    pdfmenubar=true,       
    pdffitwindow=true,    
    pdfstartview={FitH},   
    pdftitle={Anteproyecto TEG Miguelangel Leon},   
    pdfauthor={Miguelangel Leon},     
    pdfsubject={Anteproyecto TEG},
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=RoyalBlue,
    citecolor=RoyalBlue,
    urlcolor=RoyalBlue  
}

%%%%%%Ecuaciones quimicas%%%%%%
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{reaction}
%%% >> for article <<
%\renewcommand\thereaction{\arabic{reaction}}
%%% << for article <<
%%% >> for report and book >>
\renewcommand\thereaction{\thechapter.\arabic{reaction}}
\@addtoreset{reaction}{chapter}
%%% << for report and book <<

\newcommand\reactiontag{\refstepcounter{reaction}\tag{\thereaction}}
\newcommand\reaction@[2][]{\begin{equation}\ce{#2}%
\ifx\@empty#1\@empty\else\label{#1}\fi%
\reactiontag\end{equation}}
\newcommand\reaction@nonumber[1]{\begin{equation*}\ce{#1}%
\end{equation*}}
\newcommand\reaction{\@ifstar{\reaction@nonumber}{\reaction@}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[sorting=none,citestyle=numeric-comp,firstinits=true,doi=false,isbn=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referencias}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{longtable}            
\usepackage{afterpage}         

\usepackage[hypcap,footnotesize,bf]{caption}     
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[top=4cm, left=3cm, right=2cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\chaptertitlename}{CAPITULO}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{-25pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\raggedleft \Large}{ \color{BrickRed}{\chaptertitlename} \hspace{1ex} \thechapter .  \hspace{1ex} }{0pt}
{\bf}


\titleformat{\section}{\Large \bfseries \color{RoyalBlue}}{\thesection}{15pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large \bfseries \color{RoyalBlue}}{\thesubsection}{15pt}{}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{Royal}{HTML}{5BA8FF}   
\definecolor{verde}{HTML}{025F09}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.85pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhfoffset[LR]{2.1cm}
\fancyhead[LE]{\colorbox{Royal}{\color{white}{ \hspace{1.1cm} \textbf{\thepage} }} \hspace{1mm} \scriptsize \emph{\textcolor{BrickRed}{\rightmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\scriptsize \emph{\textcolor{BrickRed}{\leftmark}} \hspace{1mm} \normalsize \colorbox{Royal}{\color{white}{ \textbf{\thepage}\hspace{1.1cm}}}}

\linespread{1.3}

\newcommand{\localtextbulletone}{\textcolor{RoyalBlue}{\raisebox{.45ex}{\rule{.6ex}{.6ex}}}}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\localtextbulletone} 
\addtolength{\parskip}{3mm} 

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\input{portada.tex}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLA DE CONTENIDO}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LISTA DE FIGURAS}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LISTA DE TABLAS}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
\mbox{}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INTRODUCCION}
\chapter*{INTRODUCCION}
\markboth{INTRODUCCION}{INTRODUCCION}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\input{introduccion.tex}

\chapter{REVISION BIBLIOGRAFICA}
\label{cha:revb}
\input{revision-bibliografica.tex}

\chapter{OBJETIVOS}
\input{objetivos}

\chapter{METODOLOGIA EXPERIMENTAL}
\label{cha:mete}
\input{metexp.tex}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=REFERENCIAS]

\end{document}
```

The log shows 0 errors.

I'm very sorry to ask but I already try to find a similar problem in the internet with no success.

Answer (score 3):

Just comment the line with `\usepackage{refcheck}`. Have a look on ctan (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcheck) for the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! that was the problem. I was just using the package to check the uncited bibliography.